# (almost) always have Polymer definition inside a closure?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

For complicated elements, is is a good practice to (almost) always have Polymer definition inside a closure to keep all the variables and methods which should only be modified internally private, as opposed to attaching them to the element (e.g. 'this')?

Like following:

```
<polymer-element name="animating-element">
   <script>


    (function() { 

       var privateObj = {};

       privateObj.internalState = 0; 

       //private static method
       privateObject.setupState = function(polymerObject) {
          if(polymerObject.stateExposedToOutside == /* some conditions */) { 
             privateObject.internalState = 1;
          }

       }

       Polymer('animating-element', {
          stateExposedToOutside: 0,
          ready: function() {

              privateObj.setupState(this);
              this.animate();

          },
          animate: function() {

          }
      });
    })();

   </script>

</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Would you give an example of how `privateObj` can be accessed from outside the component? because that is precisely what I’m looking for with a third party component that I want to override a few private objects.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer this is not a very useful approach in general. Also this is a very old question and I am not aware of the recent developments. But now I am less picky about isolating internal state variables and I think just starting a variable with _ is enough to signal user that it is not a great idea to modify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No!
There is one major problem with above code. Since privateObj is sealed by the closure, it is static (e.g. shared among all the instances of that component) and cannot keep the state for each of them.

Moreover the idea is that the state of each component solely be determined by its attributes so keeping an internal state object should be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

This is completely up to you as the element designer. Variables in the closure will be as `private` as it gets in JavaScript. Properties on the prototype are generally hackable.

One camp values isolation, and prefers privatizing as much as possible to prevent errors and improve upgrade-ability.

Another camp values open APIs, and prefers allowing the developer access, in order to solve problems the author didn't envision.

You get to decide which camp you are in (or invent a new one =P).

Comment: Thanks Scott, I was trying to stay in the second camp (at least because of the simplicity of implementation) but for the sake of component stability I had to hide many things from outside and I ended up with this pattern for all the components.

Comment: Just found a problem. privateObj.internalState is static and shared between all instances of the component. How is it possible to make it private but non-static?

Comment: Asked above in a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461109/private-non-static-variables-in-polymer