# Private non-static variables in polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

How is it possible to have private non-static variables in polymer?

In:

```
<polymer-element name="component-one">
   <script>

       Polymer('component-one', {
       internalState = 1,    
       ready() {
               this.anotherInternalState = 1;
           }
           /* more variables and functions */
      });

   </script>

</polymer-element>
```

both internalState and anotherInernalState are exposed to outside (e.g. accessible through something like:

```
document.querySelector('component-one').internalState
```

(Which might be undesirable when changing internalState from outside makes the component unstable.)

where as in:

```
<polymer-element name="component-two">
   <script>

    (function() { 

       var internalState = 1;


       Polymer('component-two', {
          /* some variables and functions */
      });
    })();

   </script>

</polymer-element>
```

internalState is hidden from outside but it is static and shared across all the instances of the component.

Is there a way to have a private non-static variable inside polymer object?

Answer (score 4):

This is more of a pure JavaScript question than a Polymer question. As of ES5 there are no 'private instance members' in JavaScript, although ES6 brings some new tools.

My suggestion is to use the old convention of prepending private instance variables with underscore (`_internalState`).

Otherwise, you have to get tricky with maps and closures.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I was just looking at FB React and saw that React has a state property which is private to the component. Isn't something like that useful enough to be added to Polymer as well? (to my humble opinion it is :)

Comment: Hope this feature is proposed in 0.8 and 1.0 API

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to maintain a private static context for each instance of your element. There are [some hints](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#global) in the doc as to how to do that. First off I'd start with keeping track of live instances:

```
var instances = [];
Polymer('foo-bar', {
    // ...
    attached: function() {
        instances.push(this);
    },
    detached: function(){
        instances = instances.filter(function(instance){
            return instance !== this;
        }.bind(this));
    },
    // ...
});
```

Then you could add a private method to get access to your instance private context:

```
var instances = [], contexts = [];
Polymer(/* ... */);
function getPrivateContext(instance){
    return contexts[instances.indexOf(instance)];
}
```

And wire it up all together more elegantly:

```
var instances = [];
Polymer('foo-bar', {
    // ...
    attached: function() {
        instances.push({
            element: this,
            context: {}
        );
    },
    detached: function(){
        instances = instances.filter(function(instance){
            return instance.element !== this;
        }.bind(this));
    },
    // ...
    whatever: function(){
        var privateThis = private(this);
    }
});
function private(element){
    return instances.filter(function(instance){
        return instance.element === element;
    })[0].context;
}
```

Haven't tested it but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 where you have symbols, you can do

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
    <script type="text/javascript">        
        (function () {
            // visible to all my-element instances
            var privateKey = Symbol('Symbol description');

            Polymer({
                ready: function () {
                    // initialize object containing private properties
                    this[privateKey] = {}; // only you can touch this

                    // only those with access to 'privateKey' can can access
                    // your new ContactCard
                    this[privateKey].contactCard = new ContactCard(this);
                },
                // public method
                publicMethod: function() {

                    // accessing private data
                    doSomethingWith(this[privateKey].contactCard);
                }
            };);
        })();
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

using Symbols. This should prevent users of your element from accessing certain data of your choice. Since all instances can view the key, the data is still visible to all instances of your element. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol

Answer (score -1):

Here's the approach I've taken:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
    (function () {
        var privateStatic = Math.random();

        function ContactCard(component) {
            var mouseoverTimer;
            var privateInstance = Math.random();

            component.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
                mouseoverTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                    alert(privateStatic);
                    alert(privateInstance);
                }, 250);
            });

            component.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
                clearTimeout(mouseoverTimer);
            });

            return {

            };
        };

        Polymer({
            ready: function () {
                new ContactCard(this);
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
```

I don't show it in the example, but you can still use the `component.$.someElementId` way of accessing elements by id in the shadow root.

Aside: I feel like this style of programming allows you to decouple your components a little further from Polymer if you're into that sort of thing. You can actually use `component.shadowRoot.getElementById('someElementId')` and `component.shadowRoot.querySelector('#someElementId')` as well as other tactics if you choose and they will work in other browsers besides Chrome (including IE9 and up.)

Answer (score -1):

Just move the value assignment in one of the prototype functions, like:

```
<polymer-element name="component-two">
    <script>

        (function() { 

            var internalState;

            Polymer('component-two', {

                ready: function() {
                    internalState = 1; // Replace static value with something instance specific
                }
            });
        })();

   </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Forget that, wasn't thinking!

Comment: But how about declaring a private static array? Then, in one of the prototype functions pushing a value to that array and saving the index like `this.index = internalState.push(someValue) - 1;` and accessing it with `internalState[this.index]`. This would only expose the index outside of `<component-two>` elements. Also a `<component-two>` element would still be able to access the "internalState" of another instance.