# How to access private objects in a component's script?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24442200/1436359) the OP asked about how to avoid exposing private objets to the outside in a component. I’ve been googling around and can’t find a way to do the opposite. Say I have the component below and I want to access `privateObj` from either my web page or a parent component. How can it be done using JavaScript and the Polymer API?

```
<polymer-element name="animating-element">
   <script>    
     var privateObj = {};

     privateObj.internalState = 0; 

     //private static method
     privateObject.setupState = function(polymerObject) {
        if(polymerObject.stateExposedToOutside == /* some conditions */) { 
           privateObject.internalState = 1;
        }
     }

     Polymer('animating-element', {
        stateExposedToOutside: 0,
        ready: function() {

          privateObj.setupState(this);
          this.animate();

        },
        animate: function() {

        }
      });    
   </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: To clarify, your question is "how do I make a private object non-private?" What would be the point of being able to make stuff private then?

Comment: @ceejayoz Yep, I know exposing private stuff is against the component encapsulation premise, but if it can be done somehow I’d prefer so since it’s a third party component, and I can’t wait for the author to accept a pull request and ship the patched application. Also, that’s precisely what Polymer is all about, isn’t it, filling in the gaps, in the meanwhile to the standardization of web components.

Comment: It's not against the "premise", it's against the language's *functionality*. You likely need to fork the component until the PR is merged (or if it's rejected). It's a private object. The entire point of having it be private is that it's private.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `public` method inside `Polymer` constructor which will return the value of your `privateObj`

```
 privateObjValue:function(){
   return privateObj;
 }
```

Now you can read the value of the object using `this.privateObjValue()`(not sure how it works in `Polymer 0.5`)